# Youtube API v3 query sorted by one week viewcount

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm building a query to return a list of Youtube videos using the Youtube Data API v3. I need to order the results based on last week's (last 7 days) view count. Using the API I can only return videos sorted by total view count.

Here is the query I currently have:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&category=comedy&order=viewCount&key=[MY KEY]
```

What parameters do I need to add or modify so that I only return a list sorted by the highest view count from the last 7 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter **publishedAfter** for 7 days ago.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#publishedAfter

Comment: Great, that worked by inserting "&publishedAfter=2016-01-01T00:00:00Z" into my query.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<VideoInfo> videos = new List<VideoInfo>();

RestSharp.RestClient client = new RestClient(YT_BASE_URL +resource);
RestSharp.RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

request.AddParameter("key", APIKEY_YOUTUBE);
request.AddParameter("part", "snippet");
request.AddParameter("maxResults", (int)(maxqty));
request.AddParameter("videoCaption", "none");
request.AddParameter("type", "video");
request.AddParameter("order", "viewCount");
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(nextpagetoken))
{
    request.AddParameter("pageToken", nextpagetoken);
}

foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> param in parameters)
{
    request.AddParameter(param.Key, param.Value);
}
```